# Optimization Algorithm for Collecting a Set of Items

Tags: algorithm, set

This is analogous to an algorithm I'm in need of...

I want to purchase a complete set of trading cards - one of each card.

Each card can be bought from different vendors at different prices. If I purchase a given card from a certain vendor they sometimes offer one or more additionals cards as a bundle for an additional charge. Bundles can sometimes offer significant discounts, but some vendors sell singles that are really cheap without needing bundles.

If I have a complete price list for every single card and bundle from every vendor, can someone suggest an algorithm that would efficiently calculate (or approximate) the cheapest way to purchase a complete set of cards?

Comment: Re: "efficiently calculate (or approximate)": Definitely "approximate", not "efficiently calculate". Your problem is a generalization of the [minimum vertex cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover#Computational_problem). (Specifically: the minimum vertex cover problem is equivalent to the special case of your problem whereby each card is in exactly two bundles and each bundle has exactly the same price. In that special case, edges are cards and vertices are bundles.)

Comment: There's also (and maybe more directly) a reduction from exact subset cover, which is NP complete, too.

Answer (score 0):

First, my intuition tells me that this is at least an NP-hard problem. I don't think that you can check if a provided shopping cart is actually the cheapest in polynomial time. If you buy one card from a different vendor and choose an entirely different bundle, you may be missing cards. You may now buy those missing cards from a different vendor for a new bundle, causing a whole cascade of changes.

I'll try to formulate an application to a known NP problem with an approximate solution.

Ok, so you know not only the prices of cards and bundles, but exactly which cards you need to buy to activate the bundle offers.

This sounds like you could adapt a (modified) minimum spanning tree (MST) algorithm here.

Here's how I think you should form your DIRECTED graph:

1. Make one node for each card. Call this type of node `C`.
2. Create an extra node for each card that a vendor sells. Call this type of node `CV`.
3. Connect corresponding `CV`'s as the source to `C`'s as the destination. The weight is 0.
4. For each `CV` that has a bundle offer, create a node `BCV`. Connect from `CV` to `BCV` with the bundle's price.
5. From each `BCV`, connect to all the `C`'s in that bundle with a weight of 0.
6. Now make a root node connecting to all nodes of type `CV`, each weight equal to the vendor's price for that card.

From this formulation, you need an MST that only needs to reach nodes of type `C`. This MST would tell you which cards to buy and which bundles to buy. If you connect to a card `CV`, that means you've gotten the corresponding `C` (weights are 0 so they're free). If you additionally choose to choose to connect to the corresponding `BCV`, then you're connected to all the `C`'s in that bundle for free.

It turns out that these types of trees are called Steiner trees, and are known to be NP-hard. [This paper](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~sudipto/mypapers/dir_steiner.pdf) and [this paper](https://cedric.cnam.fr/fichiers/art_3140.pdf) that I found through a Google search seems to present an approximation algorithm for it. There are more that you can look up. However, it doesn't look like anyone has actually implemented this in some kind of Python package that's readily usable.

Comment: I drew it out in my notebook: https://imagebin.ca/v/4BbIwKRRAqxk . This approach looks very promising.

Comment: @JoelHoldsworth Tell me how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an approximate solution (and, in certain cases, the full solution) with convex optimization. The trick is that you may not need to constrain the card purchases to be an integer, because the optimum number will often be an integer anyway. Problem setup:

Say there are N cards in the complete set. Assign an index to each card, 0 thru N-1.

For each possible bundle purchase i, create a length N vector  **Cards<sub>i</sub>** that is 1 at the indices of cards it contains, and 0 at all other indices.

Also the bundle purchase has a price called **Price<sub>i</sub>**. Your free optimization variable is **Choice<sub>i</sub>**.

So you have 2 constants and one optimization variable per bundle. Then your optimization problem is:

**Minimize** sum(**Price<sub>i</sub>** * **Choice<sub>i</sub>**)

**Subject to**:

sum(**Cards<sub>i</sub>** * **Choice<sub>i</sub>**)>= ones(N,1)

**Choice<sub>i</sub>** >= 0

The ones(N,1) is your requirement for the number of cards you want to own.

You should be able to set that up pretty easily with the cvxpy library: http://www.cvxpy.org/ After solving, you'll need to check that its resulting **Choice<sub>i</sub>** variables are all near 0 or near 1. If they're not, it means your data has a pathological combination of bundles as described in mcdowella's comment below. In that case you'll need to do an NP-hard search as described in other answers. Or you can do a hack, such as buy those cards individually and accept that it's not guaranteed optimal.

Comment: Suppose there are three cards and three vendors. Each vendor has a good deal on a different pair of cards. I think the convex solution is to buy 1/2 of a pair from each vendor, thus buying each card a total of one time, 1/2 from one vendor and 1/2 from another. I think to guarantee an integer solution you need a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix. I think a special case of this problem is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover, so it is NP-complete.

Comment: Ah you're right, that is a case that breaks it: you have cards A,B,C available as individuals or as discounted pairs. The optimizer would buy 0.5 (A,B), 0.5 (B,C), and 0.5 (A,C). I'll edit my answer.